# Format date without whitespace in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

API that I use returns date as `"20090320"` which is `Y`, `m` and `d`.

**How can I format it in rails to have for example `20-03-2009`?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way, it is called unix timestamp.

Comment: @emrahbasman No, it’s not. Unix timestamps are timestamps (date + time), not dates. “20090320” as a Unix timestamp would represent 21 Aug 1970 12:38:40 UTC.

Comment: @andrew-marshall Damn i didn't read the question correctly. Such a ridiculous date format for an api.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `rails` you can use [`to_date`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Conversions/to_date):

```
"20090320".to_date
=> Fri, 20 Mar 2009
"20090320".to_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
=> "20-03-2009"
```

Comment: Imho it is the cleanest solution as fat as Rails is concerned. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

```
Date.strptime('20090320', '%Y%m%d').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: This is the best solution since it ensure the original string is parsed in the expected format. However, if the input format varies using `Date.parse` may be more effective.

Comment: `Date.parse` won't give a correct solution if say a hypothetical API returned date in YYYYDDMM format. However, with `Date.strptime`, its still possible: `Date.strptime('20092003', '%Y%d%m')`

Comment: @UtsavKesharwani `Date.parse` will work definitely.. I don't know in which case, you are saying `::parse` will not work.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: For date in YYYYDDMM format, `Date.parse("20092003")` raises `ArgumentError: invalid date`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit It doesn’t matter for this format, but it does matter for others. While `YYYYDDMM` is probably a bit uncommon, having `MMDDYY`/`DDMMYY`/`YYMMDD` are common ones where explicitness may be needed.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yes,,I figured out that. Myself actually never had met such an abnormal format.. So I couldn’t think about it. Anyway.. Thanks for your useful reply.

Answer (score 6):

Do as below using [`Date::parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) and [`Date#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime):

```
require 'date'
d = Date.parse "20090320" # => #<Date: 2009-03-20 ((2454911j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
d.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') # => "20-03-2009"
```

In one line write as

```
Date.parse("20090320").strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

The method's that you're looking for are `parse` and `strftime` on the `Date` class.

You'll need to require `date` from the ruby standard library for this to work though.

Here is an example

```
require 'date'

puts Date.parse("20090320").strftime("%d-%m-%Y") # 20-03-2009
```